# Antonym for verb "vote"

Tags: verbs

I'm looking for a verb which is an antonym of *vote,* e.g. "unvote" or "de-vote", meaning **to rescind or cancel** the previously-made vote.

Comment: Do you mean (1) abstain from voting, (2) rescind or cancel the previously made vote, or (3) reverse the previously made vote—for example, from "yes" to "no"—assuming a simple reversal is possible? What is the precise meaning that you're trying to get across?

Comment: 'Vote' has so many senses that 'dissuade' (from voting) is one antonym.

Comment: Also, you didn't say what a thesaurus had? Why did their suggestions not work?

Comment: @JasonBassford, (2) is the option i meant.

Comment: @Mitch there's none of them related to my case.

Comment: @Zekfad You really should include your research in your question, with your reasons for rejecting the result. Also, please do edit questions with clarifications (there's an **edit** link underneath) rather than answer in comments. Admittedly editing is less obvious than the requirement to show your research, so I've included your clarification for you here.

Comment: Other than "rescind," **"recant"** could work. Check out its definition [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/recant).  However, "recant" refers to the *idea* maintained by a person than their actual vote.  Nonetheless, it could work (depending on the specific context).  Let me know what you think.  I can also convert this to an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @JohnB. this is what i was looking for, thanks. Post it as answer, so i could accept it.

Comment: @Zekfad Done! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Recant"** could be the word for which you are looking.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/recant) defines it as:

> To announce in public that your past beliefs or statements were wrong and that you no longer agree with them.

*Note: "recant" focuses more on the **idea** maintained by the voter than the vote itself.  Nonetheless, it could still be applied to show that someone has rescinded their **support** for an idea.*

Comment: *Recant* can't function by itself as a single-word equivalent of 'rescind or cancel the previously-made vote', because it requires some context to make it clear that the recantation applies to a previously made vote, rather than something else. Also, the etymology of *recant*, as well as the quoted definition, make it difficult to apply it to the vote rescissions that are done secretly or, at least, quietly. It is thus somewhat unclear why the OP regarded it as an improvement over *rescind*.

Comment: @jsw29 I agree. I posted it as a comment first just to put it out there, and the OP said it satisfied their requirements. I let them know that it wasn't the same as "rescind," but they were okay with it. They told me to post it as an answer, so I did. Personally, I also think "rescind" works better.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't such a thing -- vote is an action where there is no antonym. There really isn't even a "vote against", only voting for something or some person or another. As others have said above, you can (sometimes) rescind a vote, or cancel it, but that's doing something to a vote already cast.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this comment was downvoted the instant I posted it -- literally in one screen refresh's time it was downvoted.

Comment: I was looking for a verb which will mean something like "retract vote", but in a singe word. Like do/redo/undo.

Comment: @Zekfad here on ELU we have a few seconds to "undo votes" if we voted accidentally or change our minds.

Comment: There very much is such a thing as voting against, if the voting is about a proposal.